# Разработка и отладка алгоритмов и программ

Tags: c

Разработка и отладка алгоритмов и программ обработки строк символов.

> Дана строка символов, состоящая из букв английского алфавита и пробелов. Напишите программу, которая подсчитывает, сколько раз в строке встречается каждая буква алфавита.

Разработка и отладка алгоритмов и программ с использованием структур данных.

> У администратора железнодорожных касс имеется информация о свободных местах в поездах на текущие сутки в следующем виде: пункт назначения, время отправления, число свободных мест. Вывести информацию о числе свободных мест в поездах, следующих до заданного пункта назначения.

Обработка массивов.

> Дана квадратная целочисленная матрица F[m] [m]. Найти суммы элементов тех строк, имеющих четные элементы на главной диагонали.

Comment: По вопросу о строках - регистр учитывать?

Comment: Элементы главной диагонали - это такие a[i][j] у которых i и j равны.
Проверка на четность: if ((a[i][i] & 1) == 0) { s += a[i][i]; }

Цикл, надеюсь, сами нарисуете. Заодно посмотрите, в каком виде представлены в машине **целые**. Станет понятно, зачем (a[i][i] & 1) == 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая, что самый большой код у буквы 'z' можно разместить массив счетчиков нужного размера:

```
int size = 'z'+1, i,
    lcnt[size];
```

Проверка, что символ это буква латинского алфавита:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
char *s = ....;
...
if (isalpha(s[i]) {
    lcnt[s[i]]++; // буква латинского алфавита
}
```

Печатаем результат

```
for (i = 'A'; i < size; i++) { // распечатаем счетчики
    if (isalpha(i))
        printf ("letter %c %d times\n",i,lcnt[i]);
}
```

Обратите внимание как используются типы **int** и **char** в данном случае.

Comment: и это турбо си не поймет. размер массива не может быть переменной

Comment: Тогда (если трубо-си не понимает) легко написать int lcnt['z'+1]; Это точно поймет.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s;
cin.getline(s);
map <char, int> ss;
for(int i = 0; i <= s.size(); i++){
 if(s[i]!=' ')
 ss[s[i]]++;
}
..
```

Comment: турбо си такое не поймет

Comment: Да уж. Какие шаблоны, если - Си